# Хотел создать таблицу

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `vip_users` (`account_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL default 'unknown', `lastvisit` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0, `group` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, `expires` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0);

INSERT INTO vip_users (account_id, name, lastvisit, group, expires) VALUES (101156114, 'XeNuS', 1603818415, 'vip1', 0);
```

далее последовала ошибка:

Ошибка

SQL запрос:

```
INSERT INTO vip_users (account_id, name, lastvisit, group, expires) VALUES (101156114, 'XeNuS', 1603818415, 'vip1', 0);
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group, expires) VALUES (101156114, 'XeNuS', 1603818415, 'vip1', 0)' at line 1
```

Тип сервера: MariaDB 
Версия сервера: 10.0.38-MariaDB - MariaDB Server 
Версия PHP: 5.4.16

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь в том, что в команде используется зарезервированное слово *group* в качестве имени поля. Чтобы команда выполнилась, его нужно экранировать косыми кавычками: `group`.